# file-truename and tramp

Tags: org-mode, org-export, tramp, filenames

Is these a function that behaves like `file-truename` on local files, but does not add the `/protocol:host:` prefix on remote files?
Currently if I run

```
(file-truename "./file.ext")
```

while in a remote directory, I get `"/ssh:host:/remote/path/file.ext"`. but
I just want  `"/remote/path/file.ext"`

The reason that I am asking is that pdf export in org-mode does not work on remote file for me. I have tracked the problem down to the call
`(org-latex-compile "./myfile.org")`
which uses `file-truename` to produce the actual file name that is supplied to the latex shell call. This causes problems on remote files because the tramp prefix is included in the shell call. I would like to write a patch for this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem with org -> PDF export? I have the same issue now with remote image files in my org source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior as described by you is the intended one. If you want only the remote pathname, you must call

> (file-remote-p (file-truename "./file.ext") 'localname)

Answer (score 1):

```
(expand-file-name "./file.ext")
=> "/home/brian/file.ext"
```